# How to save each value from an array to database in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to store each value from an array.
For example the form sends me this data:
`"attendance"=>{"event_id"=>"6", "member_id"=>["16", "28", "26"]}`
I'd like the database to store the data as:

```
INSERT INTO "attendances" ("event_id", "member_id") VALUES ("6", "16")
INSERT INTO "attendances" ("event_id", "member_id") VALUES ("6", "28")
INSERT INTO "attendances" ("event_id", "member_id") VALUES ("6", "26")
```

I've tried to use the usual way of inserting data in Rails, but it failed because the `member_id`s didn't get passed (I've tried to print the `member_id`s after the `Attendance.new(attendance_params)`):

```rb
def create
    @attendance = Attendance.new(attendance_params)
    # puts @attendance[:event_id]
    # puts @attendance[:member_id] -> Nothing showed up here.

    if @attendance.save
      flash[:success] = "Successfully created"
      redirect_to new_attendance_path
    else
      @error_msg = @attendance.errors.full_messages
      flash[:error] = @error_msg # Prints ["Member must exist"]
      redirect_to new_attendance_path
    end
  end
```

I've also tried creating a new function in the model to change the `Attendance.new` but it'll return
`` NoMethodError - undefined method `new_each' for #<Class:0x000000000d1e7280>: app/controllers/attendances_controller.rb:17:in `create' ``
This is my current model:

```rb
class Attendance < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :member
  
  # def new_each(attendance)
  #   attendance_event = attenance[:event_id]
  #   attendance_members = attendance[:member_id]

  #   I tried to iterate and save each data here.
  # end
end
```

So, how do I save each value from an array input (from the form) and save it to database?
Any answers and comment will be very appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are trying to add attendance in bulk, For that you can do 2 things,

1. use gem `bulk_insert`, it's very easy to use here is the link https://github.com/jamis/bulk_insert
2. you need to iterate through all the members and events from params and create a record for each. though it's a very dirty way.

sample code would be like this. you can modify it as per your need.

```
   errors = {}
   attendance_params[:member_id].each do |member_id|
       attendence = Attendence.new(event_id:attendance_params[:event_id], member_id: member_id)
       errors[member_id] = "Could not save attendance, error = 
                             attendance.errors.full_messages" unless 
                             attendence.save
   end
```